# Local transparent proxy SSLSplit causes forwarding loop

Tags: networking, iptables, ssl, proxy, nat

I am trying to debug an application which sends RPCs via HTTPS. In order to read the actual RPC content, I am trying to use SSLSplit on the same machine as the application to MITM the connection. To that end, I set up a rule in my iptables NAT table which routes all traffic not coming from a root application through `127.0.0.1:8443`:

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m owner ! --uid-owner root --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8443
```

Subsequently, I run `sslsplit -D -k key.pem -c cert.pem -P  https 127.0.0.1 8443` as `root` to prevent outbound traffic from SSLSplit (to the destination server) from being redirected back to SSLSplit. Nevertheless, I get `Error 24 on listener: Too many open files`, which according to https://github.com/droe/sslsplit/issues/93#issuecomment-96894847 can be attributed to too many sockets being opened. This can be a symptom of traffic sent by SSLSplit being looped back into SSLSplit.

I am at a loss as to what I am doing wrong given that SSLSplit is running as root and root traffic is not affected by the redirect rule. Furthermore, I checked if my iptables rule is correct by executing curl twice, once as root and once as non-root. As expected, the non-root curl doesn't work (`curl: (7) Failed to connect to unix.stackexchange.com port 443: Connection refused`) while the root curl works perfectly (==> not affected by the iptables rule).

**Questions:**

1. Given that SSLSplit is running as root, how can my iptables rule create a loop that causes traffic sent from SSLSplit to be fed back into itself?
2. How can I fix this to finally be able to read the communication?

An excerpt from the output I get when trying to visit https://unix.stackexchange.com in my browser with SSLSplit running:

```
SNI peek: [www.gravatar.com] [complete]
Connecting to [192.0.73.2]:443
<repeated 96 times>

SNI peek: [platform-lookaside.fbsbx.com] [complete]
SNI peek: [www.gravatar.com] [complete]
Connecting to [157.240.17.15]:443
Connecting to [192.0.73.2]:443
<repeated some more times>

SNI peek: [www.gravatar.com] [complete]
Connecting to [192.0.73.2]:443
<repeated 95 times>

SNI peek: [platform-lookaside.fbsbx.com] [complete]
SNI peek: [www.gravatar.com] [complete]
Connecting to [157.240.17.15]:443
Connecting to [192.0.73.2]:443
<repeated some more times>

Error 24 on listener: Too many open files
Main event loop stopped (reason=0).
Child pid 12445 exited with status 0
```

Comment: "trying to debug  an application" Why don't you use a network namespace? Easy transparent MITM (or even just use Wireshark). No need to mess around with SSLsplit.

Comment: Well because SSLsplit was recommended to me :') I tried  Wireshark initially; I am aware of the SSLKEYLOGFILE way of capturing the master secret though it didn't seem to work in my case... The situation is that I am building an app that interfaces with an existing application (Infura) via JSON-RPC sent over HTTPS.  To really understand the message flow and to be able to diagnose my app, I need to MITM the traffic.

Comment: @A.B indeed, good catch! It was as you hinted just a typo in the question, on my system I of course used -A. Another relevant note: I don't have any other rules in the NAT OUTPUT chain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading OP's [very same linked comment](https://github.com/droe/sslsplit/issues/93#issuecomment-96894847):

> Add an input interface so that only inbound connections are sent to
> sslsplit, e.g. if your LAN facing interface is eth0 and your WAN
> facing interface is eth1,
>
> ```
> iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
> ```

which isn't what was done and thus couldn't warn about how running as *root* user is handled by `sslsplit`.

Actually the `sslsplit` command when run as *root*, drops privileges by switching [to user `nobody`](https://github.com/droe/sslsplit/blob/0.5.5/defaults.h#L36) unless configured otherwise:

> ```c
> /*
>  * User to drop privileges to by default.  This user needs to be allowed to
>  * create outbound TCP connections, and in some configurations, perform DNS
>  * resolution.
>  *
>  * Packagers may want to use a specific service user account instead of
>  * overloading nobody with yet another use case.  
> [...]
>  */
> #define DFLT_DROPUSER "nobody"
> ```

This is done to the forked "worker" subprocess. I'm not sure there is an interest to run this as *root* unless binding to a low port.

So what should be done is:

- run `sslsplit` as a normal user

  It won't change uid or gid, just ensure that the application to intercept doesn't run as this user. Change the redirect to:

  ```
  iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m owner ! --uid-owner normaluser --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8443
  ```
- or configure *sslsplit* to use a dedicated user and/or group when run as root.

  See [configuration file](https://manpages.debian.org/sslsplit.conf.5#User) or options [`-u`](https://manpages.debian.org/sslsplit.1#u) and [`-m`](https://manpages.debian.org/sslsplit.1#m) for this purpose. I'd use (or create and use) the group `proxy` for this purpose. and then would use `! --gid-owner proxy`.

Comment: I recall checking uid/gid for one of the two sslsplit processes and it had uid/group set to 0, so I expected it to actually be root. Maybe I checked the parent instead of the worker process... Either way, it works like a charm now, I did your second suggestion by adding the `-u proxy` option!